# Spring api gateway return empty response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

i am getting empty response when i use spring security with spring api gateway.
I have a separate auth server.
These are my configurations.
APi Gateway yml config:

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  mvc:
    log-request-details: true
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        connect-timeout: 1000
        response-timeout: 5s
        wiretap: true
      httpserver:
        wiretap: true
      routes:
        - id: service1
          uri: lb://example-service
          predicates:
            - Path=/first/**
        - id: auth-server
          uri: lb://auth-server
          predicates:
            - Path=/api/auth/**
      default-filters:
        #- TokenRelay=
        #- SaveSession
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          gateway-password:
            provider: spring
            client-id: admin
            client-secret: password
            authorization-grant-type: password
            scope: openid
            client-name: gateway-password
          gateway-client-creds:
            provider: spring
            client-id: user1
            client-secret: password
            authorization-grant-type: refresh_token
            scope: openid
            client-name: gateway-client-creds
        provider:
          spring:
            token-uri: http://auth-server:9000/api/auth/token

client-registration-id: gateway-password

logging:
  level:
    root: debug
    org.springframework: debug
    reactor.netty.http.client: DEBUG
    org.springframework.cloud.gateway: DEBUG
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8083/eureka
```

API Gateway OauthConfig.java

```
package com.heal.gateway.config.security;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebClientHttpRoutingFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WebClientWriteResponseFilter;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.headers.HttpHeadersFilter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.*;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.reactive.function.client.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.endpoint.OAuth2ParameterNames;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class OauthConfig {

    @Value("${client-registration-id}")
    private String clientRegistrationId;




    @Bean
    public WebClientHttpRoutingFilter webClientHttpRoutingFilter(
            WebClient webClient, ObjectProvider<List<HttpHeadersFilter>> headersFilters) {
        return new WebClientHttpRoutingFilter(webClient, headersFilters);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClientWriteResponseFilter webClientWriteResponseFilter() {
        return new WebClientWriteResponseFilter();
    }

    @Bean
    WebClient webClient(ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager) {
        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2Client =
                new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(authorizedClientManager);
        oauth2Client.setDefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClient(true);
        oauth2Client.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId);



        return WebClient.builder()

                .filter(oauth2Client)
                //.clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector())
                //.filter(oauth)
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager(
            ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository,
            ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository authorizedClientRepository) {

        ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProvider authorizedClientProvider =
                ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientProviderBuilder.builder()
                        .password()
                        .refreshToken()
                        .build();

        DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager authorizedClientManager =
                new DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
                        clientRegistrationRepository, authorizedClientRepository);
        authorizedClientManager.setAuthorizedClientProvider(authorizedClientProvider);
        authorizedClientManager.setContextAttributesMapper(contextAttributesMapper());
        return authorizedClientManager;
    }


    private Function<OAuth2AuthorizeRequest, Mono<Map<String, Object>>> contextAttributesMapper() {
        return authorizeRequest -> {
            Map<String, Object> contextAttributes = Collections.emptyMap();
            ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange = authorizeRequest.getAttribute(ServerWebExchange.class.getName());
            String username = Objects.requireNonNull(serverWebExchange).
                    getRequest().getQueryParams().getFirst(OAuth2ParameterNames.USERNAME);
            String password = serverWebExchange.getRequest().getQueryParams().getFirst(OAuth2ParameterNames.PASSWORD);

            if (StringUtils.hasText(username) && StringUtils.hasText(password)) {
                contextAttributes = new HashMap<>();
                contextAttributes.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.USERNAME_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, username);
                contextAttributes.put(OAuth2AuthorizationContext.PASSWORD_ATTRIBUTE_NAME, password);
            }
            return Mono.just(contextAttributes);
        };
    }

}
```

API Gateway - SecurityConfig.java

```
package com.heal.gateway.config.security;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain configure(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.headers().cache().disable().frameOptions().disable().xssProtection().disable().contentTypeOptions().disable().and()
                .csrf().disable().authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().permitAll()).oauth2Client()
                .and().
                oauth2Login();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Now when i hit any api via api gateway i get 200 but every time the response is empty. Please help i am stuck on this forever.
Let me know if more details are needed.

Comment: so apparently these two beans are causing the problem WebClientHttpRoutingFilter and WebClientWriteResponseFilter. I have removed them and will post my understanding further